# Why is the return type according to C# Not nullable despite being explicitly marked as nullable?

Tags: c#, expression

I have the following Interface definition:

```
Task<TResult?> ProjectSecure<TResult>(
    string id,
    IIdentityUser user,
    Expression<Func<T, TResult>> select,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
)
```

It's similar to how `FirstOrDefault()` works except it is also doing a select.

`TResult` on the return type is explicitly nullable, but Visual Studio always sees the result as non-nullable.  I looked at the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and it uses basically identical syntax (except `Func` return of bool obviously) but sees it as nullable.

Seems like it's determining the type of `TResult` from the `select` parameter, which is fine, but then ignoring the ? on the return.

How do I convince the compiler that the return type should be nullable?

Comment: Your sample isn't complete. Where does T come from?

Comment: Can you share an implementation example? What actual message (and where) are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on TResult?

Comment: There weren't any constraints. Adding where TResult: struct fixed it per the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C# 9.0 `T?` means the following if no generic type constraint is defined.

| T | T? |
| --- | --- |
| int | int |
| int? | int? |
| string | string? |
| string? | string? |

See [nullable references with generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics).

So if you call your method with a non-nullable value type then `T?` will be the same non-nullable value type.

Of course, your `select` parameter can trick the static code analysis as well depending on what the actual implementation of your method is.

To restrict your `TResult` to be a non-nullable reference type then add `where TResult : class` constraint.

Alternatively, if you want to allow both non-nullable value type and non-nullable reference type then add `where TResult : notnull` constraint.

Comment: Bizzare.  Adding where TResult: struct fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `where TResult : struct` also fixes the problem since it means that `TResult` can be only a non-nullable value type, hence `TResult?` can be only a nullable value type. So to sum up, you can restrict `TResult` to be a non-nullable type with one of these constraints: `class`, `struct` and `notnull`.